# Can I classify time survival predictions?

Tags: r, classification, survival, random-forest, cox-model

I want to create a model to predict a new, unseen, observation's credit loan default time.

I know that I could use a cox regression.

I'd like to use a Conditional Inference Tree, however, despite many using KM for descriptive statistics.

What I had in mind was to split my data into training and testing subsets (my original dataset has 1000 observations), and then classify all predictions as correct if the predicted default times were equal to or greater than than the actual default times.

I'm unsure of what to do for observations that had not yet defaulted (or that would never) and how I would classify those.

Assuming that there is a method I could use for observations that hadn't defaulted, I would then prune my tree until I land on a model's predictions I feel comfortable with.

Using the Specificity, Sensitivity, FalsePositives, & FalseNegatives, I would then use the most optimal tree to conduct the prediction on the new unseen observation.

**How is my thinking?** 
**Is there even a method to classify on censored observations?** 
**Is anything like this used in industry?**

Comment: This is a classic survival (reliability) analysis problem.  Have you looked into those? Many tools exist to do that ( scikit survival, lifelines, deepweibull, deepsurv, tfp ...)

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg Do you mean to say that I should only use Cox Regression? I'm an R user

Comment: take a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ciTools/vignettes/ciTools_survreg_vignette.html .  Cox regression is more useful for inference ( how covariates change risk), not for predicting the actual times.  For that accelerated failure time (AFT) models are useful

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763297/how-do-i-compare-the-effectiveness-of-survival-models